# How to ignore a part of html code that has already ignore in it

Tags: html

```
<body>
1
<br/>
2
<br/>
<!--3-->
<br/>
4
</body>
```

In this example I want to ignore all the code from 1 to 4 as I did with 3 without removing 3 ignore tag.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. What are you asking? HTML doesn't support nested comments. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score -2):

The browser parses every `<!--` as start of a comment and `-->` as its end.
If you have comment inside another comment, like:

```
<!-- a
<!-- b -->
-->
```

the browser will parse:

```
<!-- a
<!-- b -->
```

as comment and print the `-->` because he thinks the `<!-- a...` is closed with `b -->`.

You need to close the comment tag before the next comment and open again afterwards

Comment: No, [it won't](http://jsfiddle.net/33XRu/)

Comment: You right, guys.... Tired. Edited the answer